# find out the missing expressions

Tags: formation-of-numbers

> 10 10 10 10 = 1
>   10 10 10 10 = 2
>   10 10 10 10 = 3
>   10 10 10 10 = 4
>   10 10 10 10 = 5
>   10 10 10 10 = 6
>   10 10 10 10 = 7
>   10 10 10 10 = 8
>   10 10 10 10 = 9
>   10 10 10 10 = 10

You can only add expressions, you cannot change any numbers.

Comment: What are the allowed mathematical operators?

Comment: Hi Peggy, and welcome! When you make this kind of problems, you need to say what we can use. Is it just the symbols `+` `-` `*` and `/`, or maybe something more? (If we can use anything, then it's not a very interesting problem anymore. [We already know how to solve all of those](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/handling-underspecified-make-this-number-from-these-digits-questions))

Comment: all symbols, including brackets and roots

Comment: @Peggy Could you please give us a list of symbols? As Bass pointed, if you allow all symbols the solution is easy.

Comment: I did some of them;

Comment: (10+10) / (10+ 10) =!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete answer with "simple" operators (+, -, *, /, ⁰, ², ³, !, log):

> (10 + 10) / (10 + 10) = 1
>  (10 / 10) + (10 / 10) = 2
>  (10 + 10 + 10) / 10 = 3
>  ((10 / 10) + (10 / 10))² = 4
>  Another one : log(10) + log(10) + log(10) + log(10) = 4
>  (10 * 10) / (10 + 10) = 5
>  ((10 + 10 + 10) / 10)! = 6 (thanks to [Kepotx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44790/kepotx))
>  10 - 10⁰ - 10⁰ - 10⁰ = 7  (thanks to [Stefano Lonati](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20162/stefano-lonati))
>  Another one : 10 - log(10 * 10 * 10) = 7 (thanks to [Stefano Lonati](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20162/stefano-lonati))
>  ((10 / 10) + (10 / 10))³ = 8
>  Another one : 10 * log(10) - log(10) - log(10) = 8 (thanks to [Stefano Lonati](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20162/stefano-lonati))
>  ((10 * 10) - 10) / 10 = 9
>  10 + (10 - 10) * 10 = 10

Comment: (10 * 10) - 10 - 10 = 80, not 8

Comment: im not sure if we can add ^0, ^2 or ^3, isn't that adding numbers?

Comment: @Kepotx Not really a number, it is a mathematical operator but we write it with numbers.

Comment: @Kepotx Ok:  10-(log(10*10*10)) = 7

Comment: Hi Anyone can explain the ;

Comment: 10 10 10  10 =6  and 10 10 10 10 = 7, i dont understand, thx

Comment: @Peggy For the = 6 it is factorial(3) so 3*2*1, and for the 7 my notation is a bit non-conventional but it's ^0, so 10^0 = 1

Answer (score 9):

Thinking a little outside of the box, here's my answer:

> 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 1
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 2
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 3
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 4
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 5
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 6
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 7
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 8
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 9
>  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 != 10

where the operators I used were:

> `+` - the addition operator
>  `!` - logical NOT

This answer can be extended to any $n$ for {$n \in \mathbb N, \mathbb Z, \mathbb R, \mathbb Q\}$ with only one exception for

> n = 40

Comment: Hahahahaha, this is so clever :P

Comment: For anyone wondering why these types of puzzles need to be well-specified, this answer is why.

Comment: To be quite honest I expected this answer to be down voted, but didn't mind since it showed the OP the need to be specific

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible separate the number 10 in 1 and 0?

> 1*0+1*0+1*0+1+0 = 1 
>  1*0+1*0+1+0+1+0 = 2 
>  1*0+1+0+1+0+1+0 = 3 
>  1+0+1+0+1+0+1+0 = 4 
>  10/(1+0+1+0)+ 1*0 = 5 
>  10/(1+0+1+0)+ 1 + 0 = 6 
>  10-1+0-1+0-1+0 = 7 
>  10-1+0-1+0+1*0 = 8 
>  10-1+0+1*0+1*0 = 9 
>  10-1*0-1*0-1*0 = 10

Or

> (10 + 10) / (10 + 10) = 1 
>  (10 / 10) + (10 / 10) = 2 
>  (10 + 10 + 10) / 10 = 3 
>  log(10*10) + log(10*10) = 4 
>  (10 * 10) / (10 + 10) = 5 
>  ((10 + 10 + 10) / 10)! = 6 
>  10 - log(10*10*10) = 7 
>  
>  10 * log(10) - log(10) - log(10) = 8 
>  
>  ((10 * 10) - 10) / 10 = 9 
>  10 + (10 - 10) * 10 = 10

Comment: no, cant separate the  all 10 numbers

Answer (score 0):

A simple general solution using Log, +,-,*,(),^

> $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^1)}  = 1$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^2)}  = 2$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^3)}  = 3$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^4)}  = 4$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^5)}  = 5$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^6)}  = 6$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^7)}  = 7$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^8)}  = 8$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^9)}  = 9$$
>  $$10*(10 - 10) + \log{(10^{10})}  = 10$$

This simple approach can generate any "n"